# htmlのform上で入力したコンマ区切りの数字をjavascriptの配列として取り込みたい

Tags: javascript

htmlのform上で入力したコンマ区切りの数字をjavascriptの配列として取り込みたいのですが、
form 上　で 例えば1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9　送信して
var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];　と配列にしたいところ、
var x = ["1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"];となったり、var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]で文字列になったりします。

なにか方法がありましたら、ご教授ください。

Answer (score 0):

文字列を`,`で`split`してから、各文字列を`parseInt`すればいいのではないでしょうか。

以下デモ

```js
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var input = document.getElementById("numbers");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = input.value;
  var numbers = text.split(",").map(function(s) {
    return parseInt(s, 10);
  });
  result.textContent = JSON.stringify(numbers);
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <div>press Enter to submit</div>
  <input id="numbers" type="text" />
</form>
<div>result: <span id="result"></span></div>
```

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。parseIntの他にmap、jsonなどわかっていなかったためとても勉強になりました。

Comment: @mk `JSON.stringify`は単に表示するために使っただけです。わからないところがあったら質問してください。